# Segmentation fault issues (selenium-webdriver + rb-appscript)

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault, selenium-webdriver, rb-appscript

I'm trying to automate webscraping, making use of both the `selenium-webdriver` and the ruby port of AppleScript `rb-appscript`. However, when I try to run the code I keep running into a segmentation fault.

**Code:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'appscript'; include Appscript
require 'selenium-webdriver'

# Open instance of Firefox
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => "default")

# Open my webscraping extension
app('Firefox').activate
app("System Events").processes["firefox-bin"].menu_bars[1].menu_bar_items["Tool\
s"].menus["Tools"].menu_items["******"].click

driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
driver.quit
```

This line:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => "default")
```

Seems to be causing the issue.

When executed in separate files, the two work fine.

**selenium-webdriver:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => "default")
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
driver.quit
```

**rb-appscript:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rb-appscript'; include Appscript

app('Firefox').activate
app("System Events").processes["firefox-bin"].menu_bars[1].menu_bar_items["Tool\
s"].menus["Tools"].menu_items["******"].click
```

Any idea what the issue is? I'm new at ruby so I'm not exactly sure what is causing the issue.

**Ruby version: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patch level352)
OS: Mac OSX 10.6.8 64-bit**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the version of ruby was causing the issue. 1.8.7 is a bridge between 1.8 and 1.9, and is not recommended for use apparently. There are numerous reports of ruby 1.8.7 causing segmentation faults when using a multitude of different gems. Upgrading to the latest version (1.9.2) fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not addressing your question directly, but as a workaround you could check out Watir: http://watir.com/. I'm using it successfully with Firefox on Mac OSX 10.6.8. Something along the lines of:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto("http://google.com")
```

Comment: As far as I know Watir doesn't let you set and create the Firefox profiles you're driving with, something I need that selenium-webdriver allows you to do. Figured out the issue though, thanks!